# Dynamic height for floated elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-float

I have a list of floated dynamic elements which should be shown one after the other two elements in a row. By dynamic, I mean the elements to be shown are decided based on dynamic criteria and can be of different height. Is there any way to adjust the height of the sibling element to be equal to the height of the current element. Here is an example usecase. Divs one and two should be of the same height and divs three and four should be of the same height. Can anyone suggest me on how to accomplish this. **I cannot wrap two elements in a row since I do not know which element should be rendered beforehand.** The page contains the exhaustive list of all elements and uses angualar ng-if directive to render the required elements. As of now, I am taking the maximum height required as the min-height for all divs. But that results in lots of unnecessary extra space. Is the any other better solution?

```
 <div class="col-xlg-12">
   <div class="one col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderHugeContentElement">I have huge content</div>
   <div class="two col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderSingleLineElement">I have single line content </div>
   <div class="three col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderTwoLinesElement"> I have two lines content </div>
   <div class="four col-xlg-6" ng-fi="renderFourLinesElement">I have four lines content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a demo link if you have one. That would be easy to understand.

Comment: You probably want to stop with the floating, and go flexbox instead.

Comment: @CBroe if he is not able to wrap 2 elements, i think using flexbox also, he can only make all divs equal height. As i understood he wants two in a row with equal height

Comment: @NithinCharly `flex-wrap:wrap` helps to wrap items in a flex container to the next "line", so if you combine that with a width (or flex-shrink/grow/basis), that works out fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wo1qekxb/ (tested in Chrome only, no vendor prefixes added)

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the info. May be your fiddle is the best option for this question

Comment: @CBroe : that seems like a clean approach. My divs are a little complex with various other elements inside and I am not sure if I can adapt this approach though, as a quick check seemed to break the flow of inner components..Should work with little tweaks to inner elements i guess.. Will try the same.. thanks a lot..

Comment: Yeah, content inside of flex items might behave differently than in a “normal” element - but that should be fixable via the diverse justify and align settings. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ has a good overview of which property achieves what.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a loop to render the columns.

You can configure your loop in a way that it renders rows having 2 columns each.

The resulting HTML would look like:

```
<div class="col-xlg-12">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="one col-xlg-6">I have huge content</div>
       <div class="two col-xlg-6">I have single line content </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="three col-xlg-6"> I have two lines content </div>
       <div class="four col-xlg-6">I have four lines content </div>
   </div>
   ...
   <!-- more dynamic elements come here -->
</div>
```

This would make sure every 2 columns always sit side by side.

**Update:**

As you say that you cannot wrap elements in in a `<div class="row">`, you will have to rely on javascript. You can create a function that gets triggered whenever new elements are added to the DOM and this function sets the height of 2 adjacent elements to the highest height.

Comment: I cannot guarantee the flow of elements as I use angular ng-if to render the elements. Updated the question accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Let me take this that what you want for a row is 2 columns only and as per Hemant you are trying to use a loop for a lot of dynamic elements.

This time I'm pretty sure your divs have all equal width and as per your question, they have different heights. I suggest you do Pinterest thing.

```
<div class="col-xlg-12">
   <div class="longcolumn1 col-xlg-6">
     <div class="one col-xlg-12">I have huge content</div>
     <div class="three col-xlg-12"> I have two lines content </div>
   </div>
   <div class="longcolumn2 col-xlg-6">
     <div class="two col-xlg-12">I have single line content </div>
     <div class="four col-xlg-12">I have four lines content </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, all you have to do is loop and alternately render to longcolumn1 and longcolumn2.

---

okay i guess i understand. heres my updated answer. i made this just for you. enjoy.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>try</title>
<style>
*
{
    color:#111;
}
#row1
{
    width:100%;
}
#one
{
    background:red;
    height:300px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#two
{
    background:green;
    height:40px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#three
{
    background:blue;
    height:80px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#four
{
    background:yellow;
    height:160px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#five
{
    background:orange;
    height:580px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#six
{
    background:brown;
    height:360px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#seven
{
    background:gray;
    height:160px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="row1" class="col-xlg-12">
   <div id="one" class="one col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderHugeContentElement">I have huge content.</div>
   <div id="two" class="two col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderSingleLineElement">I have single line content </div>
   <div id="three" class="three col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderTwoLinesElement"> I have two lines content </div>
   <div id="four" class="four col-xlg-6" ng-fi="renderFourLinesElement">I have four lines content </div>
   <div id="five" class="three col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderTwoLinesElement"> I have two lines content </div>
   <div id="six" class="four col-xlg-6" ng-fi="renderFourLinesElement">I have four lines content </div>
   <div id="seven" class="three col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderTwoLinesElement"> I have two lines content </div>
</div>

<script>
// SET THIS to on or off to see changes
var sample = "on";

if(sample=="on")
{
    function call(e)
    {
        return document.getElementById(e)
    }

    var start=call("one");

    var totalofdivs = call("row1").childElementCount;
    for(var n=0;n<(totalofdivs/2);n++)
    {
        if(start.nextElementSibling)
        {
            var nextelement = start.nextElementSibling;
            var lastelement = start;
            nextelement.style.height=lastelement.offsetHeight+"px";

            start = nextelement.nextElementSibling;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

just try copy/paste to a sample notepad.html

---

So what if the other div on the right side is more larger than the div on the left?
here is my code to check which of the two are the bigger and will set their heights.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>try</title>
<style>
*
{
    color:#111;
}
#row1
{
    width:100%;
}
#one
{
    background:red;
    height:300px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#two
{
    background:green;
    height:40px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#three
{
    background:blue;
    height:80px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#four
{
    background:yellow;
    height:160px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#five
{
    background:orange;
    height:580px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#six
{
    background:brown;
    height:360px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
#seven
{
    background:gray;
    height:160px;
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="row1" class="col-xlg-12">
   <div id="one" class="one col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderHugeContentElement">I have huge content.</div>
   <div id="two" class="two col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderSingleLineElement">I have single line content </div>
   <div id="three" class="three col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderTwoLinesElement"> I have two lines content </div>
   <div id="four" class="four col-xlg-6" ng-fi="renderFourLinesElement">I have four lines content </div>
   <div id="five" class="three col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderTwoLinesElement"> I have two lines content </div>
   <div id="six" class="four col-xlg-6" ng-fi="renderFourLinesElement">I have four lines content </div>
   <div id="seven" class="three col-xlg-6" ng-if="renderTwoLinesElement"> I have two lines content </div>
</div>

<script>
// SET THIS to on or off to see changes
var sample = "on";

if(sample=="on")
{
    function call(e)
    {
        return document.getElementById(e)
    }

    var start=call("one");

    var totalofdivs = call("row1").childElementCount;
    for(var n=0;n<(totalofdivs/2);n++)
    {
        if(start.nextElementSibling)
        {
            var nextelement = start.nextElementSibling;
            var lastelement = start;

            if(nextelement.offsetHeight<lastelement.offsetHeight)
            {
                nextelement.style.height=lastelement.offsetHeight+"px";
            }
            else
            {
                lastelement.style.height=nextelement.offsetHeight+"px";
            }

            start = nextelement.nextElementSibling;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot guarantee the flow of elements as I use angular ng-if to render the elements. Updated the question accordingly

Comment: make sure to check the codes. change the sample = "on" to sample = "off" for you to see the difference

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I am actually looking for a pure css only solution..I will try your approach and update if I am not able to figure out a way with CSS..thanks..